# Add rows according to other rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, duplicates

My DataFrame object similar to this one:

```
        Product StoreFrom   StoreTo Date
1   out melon   StoreQ  StoreP  20170602
2   out cherry  StoreW  StoreO  20170614
3   out Apple   StoreE  StoreU  20170802
4   in  Apple   StoreE  StoreU  20170812
```

I want to avoid duplications, in 3rd and 4th row show same action. I try to reach

```
        Product StoreFrom   StoreTo Date    Days
1   out melon   StoreQ  StoreP  20170602    
2   out cherry  StoreW  StoreO  20170614    
5   in  Apple   StoreE  StoreU  20170812    10
```

and I got more than 10k entry. I could not find similar work to this. Any help will be very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d1 = df.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date.astype(str)))
d2 = d1.assign(Days=d1.groupby(cols).Date.apply(lambda x: x - x.iloc[0]))
d2.drop_duplicates(cols, 'last')

    io Product StoreFrom StoreTo       Date    Days
1  out   melon    StoreQ  StoreP 2017-06-02  0 days
2  out  cherry    StoreW  StoreO 2017-06-14  0 days
4   in   Apple    StoreE  StoreU 2017-08-12 10 days
```

Comment: Thank you! I do not only drop duplicates but also find the time and add a colomn to show time of transportation.